# C# Dictionary <string, list<double>> multiple keys dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, converters

I need to store the same key twice, so I tried doing this, but it ain't working. Can someone help me how to do this properly? But if the word comes only once, I want it to be stored once, and if it's 3,4,5.. still twice.

```
private void Meth()
{
    foreach (var word in document)
    {
        dict1.TryGetValue(word.Key, out myValue);

        if (bigDict.ContainsKey(word.Key))
        {
            if (word.Value >= 2)
            {
                testing.Add(word.Key, myValue);
                testing.Add(word.Key, myValue);    
            }
            else
            {
                testing.Add(word.Key, myValue);
            }                                           
        }
        else
        {
            testing.Add(word.Key, 0.123);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought about doing a lookup, but it doesn't have Add, so I made:

```
private Dictionary<Key, List<double>> testing = new Dictionary<Key, List<double>>();
```

Although I can't Add "simply" `double` to `List<double>`.

Another question is, if I will be able to use it like this later:

```
var somethingLikeDict = testing.OrderByDescending(word => word.Value)
        .Take(20)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Value);
```

How can I solve this?

@edit
This is how I changed my code, **I am getting an error that says that the key doesn't exist in dictionary/key**.

```
private Dictionary<string, List<double>> testing = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();

private void MailProbability2()
{
    foreach (var word in document)
    {
        if (bigDict.ContainsKey(word.Key))
        {
            bigDict.TryGetValue(word.Key, out myValue);

            if (word.Value >= 2)
            {
                testing.Add(word.Key, new List<double>() { myValue, myValue});    
            }
            else
            {
                testing[word.Key].Add(myValue);
            }                                      
        }
        else
        {
            testing[word.Key].Add(0.123);
        }
    }
}
```

bigDict is a dictionary which contains values I want to put into testing dictionary with values up to two.

Comment: don't use a dictionary, use a list of `Tuple<T,K>` for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add each key once in a Dictionary.
What you can do is use a List as value (as you tried).
Maybe this snippet will help you:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
var newKey = "newKey";
var newValue = 0.5;
if (myDict.ContainsKey(newKey))
{
    var list = myDict[newKey];
    if (list.Count < 2)
    {
        // Add if not yet two entries
        myDict[newKey].Add(newValue);
    }
}
else
{
    myDict.Add(newKey, new List<double>() { newValue });
}
```

Edited after your new question:

```
foreach (var word in document)
{
    double myValue;
    // See if the value exists in the big directory
    var valueExists = bigDict.TryGetValue(word.Key, out myValue);
    if (valueExists)
    {
        // See if the testing dict has the same key
        if (testing.ContainsKey(word.Key))
        {
            // It does, add the value to the list
            if (word.Value < 2)
            {
                testing[word.Key].Add(myValue);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // It doesn't, add the key with the value
            testing.Add(word.Key, new List<double>() { myValue });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I am doing, adding values from a dictionary <string, double> into a dictionary <string, list<double>>

Comment: No, you're adding more Keys to the dictionary, not more values to the value of a key to a dictionary.

Comment: important is myDict[newKey].Add(newValue);
Here the .Add acts in the Value of the KeyValuePair of the dictionary, and therefore this is the List<double> and not the dictionary which gets an Add().

Comment: I edited my question, tried to make this code work, just like yours does, but I am getting error that key does not exist in both  `testing[word.Key].Add(myValue)` and `testing.Add(word.Key, new List<double>() { myValue, myValue})`. Could you help?

Comment: you're misunderstanding quite a lot. I suggest you read some more information about the dictionary. I'll edit some more infos in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach may be better suited for a physical model of your data, for instance:

```
public class Storage
{
     public string Key { get; set; }
     public List<double> Value { get; set; }
}
```

You have a physical model, which will allow you to simply build the following:

```
var storage = List<Storage>();
```

So, whenever you add a value to your `Storage` you would then store that variable into your `List<Storage>` allowing you quick access.